# Unhandled error for request POST Loopback JS

Tags: node.js, api, loopbackjs

help me please, i'm trying to create remote method on loopback js, when my function returning callback, showing error "**Unhandled Error for request POST**" and make my respone code return to 500 response code, but still showing my result data.

Here is my code

```
'use strict';

// Define Variable Depedencies Here
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = function(Account) {
    Account.login = function(username, password, cb) {
        var data = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
        var token = jwt.sign({exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60*60), data: data}, 'secret');
        cb(token)
        // console.log(token)
    }
    Account.remoteMethod('login', {
        description: ['Login With Your Credentials'],
        http: {path: '/login', verb: 'post'},
        accepts: [
            {arg: 'username', type: 'string'},
            {arg: 'password', type: 'string'}
        ],
        returns: {arg: 'token', type: 'string'}
    })

};
```

and this my error :

```
D:\PROJECT\Backend>node .
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
Unhandled error for request POST /api/Accounts/login: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MDE4NTM2MTYsImRhdGEiOnsidXNlcm5hbWUi
OiJhZG1pbiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiMTIzNDUifSwiaWF0IjoxNTAxODUwMDE3fQ.os6ijfYyF8losGywdnrVKrHW3-DYZFSwlOVUvHyPIOk
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Found my Problem :)

i put "**err**" on callback

so this the right code

```
'use strict';

// Define Variable Depedencies Here
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = function(Account) {
    Account.login = function(username, password, cb) {
        var data = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        }
        var token = jwt.sign({exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60*60), data: data}, 'secret');
        cb(err, token)
        // console.log(token)
    }
    Account.remoteMethod('login', {
        description: ['Login With Your Credentials'],
        http: {path: '/login', verb: 'post'},
        accepts: [
            {arg: 'username', type: 'string'},
            {arg: 'password', type: 'string'}
        ],
        returns: {arg: 'token', type: 'string'}
    })

};
```